# How to switch between multiple desktops in Windows 10 using Python?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, python, cmd.exe

I'm creating a Python script for Windows 10 in which I want it to switch between multiple virtual desktops via Command Prompt without having to simulate the keystrokes.

I'm inclined to use the `os.system()` command.
E.g. In Linux there is a terminal command, `xdotool set_desktop 1`. Is there a Windows alternative for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pyautogui](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui) can send keyboard presses to the current window, but system-wide commands will, obviously, work on any window. The shortcuts to switch virtual desktops are win+ctrl+right & win+ctrl+left. The Python code to use these with pyautogui is

```python
import pyautogui as pa
pa.hotkey('win','ctrl','left') #will switch one desktop to the left
pa.hotkey('win','ctrl','right') #will switch one desktop to the right
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, Windows exposes the [IVirtualDesktopManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ivirtualdesktopmanager) class, in the Win32 api, to do this. That said, to use the [Win32 api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/) you would need to either:

1. Write your script in C# (not what you're looking for)
2. Use a python library that actually re-writes the Win32 Api to python by taking python code, and converting it to C#.

In your case, the latter would make the most sense. There are many out there that re-write the api, like [win32gui](https://pypi.org/project/win32gui/), **BUT** since virtual desktops is a feature only available in Windows 10+, there are few libraries that implement the `IVirtualDesktopManager` class and it's methods.

That said, I have heard of [pyvda](https://pypi.org/project/pyvda/) and you can see if that works, but it looks like it's still in it's early stages. Perhaps in the future, more python Win32 API-based libraries will support this class.